# media Queries: how to disable and enable javascript code in button in responsive mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

Now when `minimizing` the the screen the buttons appear and when clicking on any it shows the column but if now I `maximized` the screen it will not go back to its previous state which is showing 4 column instead in shows one column. this happens when I click on the buttons.

this how the table look like

[image]

this is how it looks when the screen `max-width:820px`

[image]

Now if I click for example on Button 3 , it will show that column but now if I maximize the screen it will still show this column instead of showing all columns like how the table originally look like.

[image]

this is my code:

```js
function myFun(){
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("second-column")]
    .forEach(e => e.style.display ="table- cell");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("third-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("forth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("fifth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
    
  }

    function myFunc(){
    
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("second-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("third-column")]
    .forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("forth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("fifth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
    
    }

    function myFunct(){
    
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("second-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("third-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("forth-column")]
    .forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("fifth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
    
   }

    function myFuncti(){
    
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("second-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("third-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("forth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("fifth-column")]
    .forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
    
    }
```

```css
        @media screen and (max-width:820px){
        
        .table,.table2,.table3{ width: 100%; }
        
        .space{ display: none; }
        .third-column,.third-col,.thi-col{ display: none; }
        .forth-column,.forth-col{ display: none; }
        .fifth-column{ display: none; }
        .table.fixed { table-layout: fixed; }
        .table2.fixed { table-layout: fixed; }
        .table3.fixed { table-layout: fixed; }
        td:first-child{ width: 50%; }
        .big{ padding: 10px 30px; }
        .box,.box2,.box3{ padding: 5px 15px; }
        
        .btn-div{ display: block !important; }
        .empty{ display: none; }
        
        }
    
        @media only  (min-width:821px) , (max-width:1140px){
        
        
        
        td:first-child{ font-size: 12px; }
        .table,.table2,.table3{
           
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-size: 13px;
        }
        th{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: 600;
  
        }
        
        span{
  
        padding-left: 4px !important;
        text-align: center;
  
        }
        
        }
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table fixed">
    <tr>
      <th style="border-bottom: none;"></th>
      <th class="space"></th>
      <th class="second-column">111</th>
      <th class="third-column">222 </th>
      <th class="forth-column">333 </th>
      <th class="fifth-column">444 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> !</td>
      <td class="space"></td>
      <td class="second-column"> 1</td>
      <td class="third-column"> 2</td>
      <td class="forth-column"> 3</td>
      <td class="fifth-column">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> %</td>
      <td class="space"></td>
      <td class="second-column"> 1</td>
      <td class="third-column"> 2</td>
      <td class="forth-column"> 3</td>
      <td class="fifth-column"> 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$</td>
      <td class="space"></td>
      <td class="second-column"> 1</td>
      <td class="third-column">2</td>
      <td class="forth-column"> 3</td>
      <td class="fifth-column"> 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> @</td>
      <td class="space"></td>
      <td class="second-column"> 1</td>
      <td class="third-column"> 2</td>
      <td class="forth-column"> 3</td>
      <td class="fifth-column"> 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> #</td>
      <td class="space"></td>
      <td class="second-column"> 1</td>
      <td class="third-column">2</td>
      <td class="forth-column"> 3</td>
      <td class="fifth-column"> 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$$ </td>
      <td class="space"></td>
      <td class="second-column"> 1</td>
      <td class="third-column"> 2</td>
      <td class="forth-column"> 3</td>
      <td class="fifth-column">4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
   <div style="text-align: center;display: none;" class="btn-div">
     <button type="button" class="this-btn add-add" id="btn-1" onClick="myFun()">1</button>
     <button type="button" class="this-btn add-add" id="btn-2" onClick="myFunc()">2</button>
     <button type="button" class="this-btn add-add"id="btn-3" onClick="myFunct()" >3</button>
     <button type="button" class="this-btn add-add" id="btn-4" onClick="myFuncti()">4</button>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the answer if anyone pass here and had the same problem as me.

the idea is to let the JS code only run when the screen width is what you want.

```
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 820px)")
myFun(x) 
myFunc(x) 
myFunct(x) 
myFuncti(x) 
// Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFun) // Attach listener function on state changes
x.addListener(myFunc) 
x.addListener(myFunct) 
x.addListener(myFuncti) 
  function myFun(){
         if (x.matches) {
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("second-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("third-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("forth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("fifth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
        }
    else{
            [...document.getElementsByClassName("second-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("third-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("forth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("fifth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
    }
    }
    
        function myFunc(){
         if (x.matches) {
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("second-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("third-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("forth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("fifth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
        }
    else{
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("second-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("third-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("forth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("fifth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
    }
    }
    
function myFunct(){
         if (x.matches) {
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("second-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("third-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("forth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("fifth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
        }
    else{
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("second-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("third-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("forth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("fifth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
    }
    }
    
        function myFuncti(){
         if (x.matches) {
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("second-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("third-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("forth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("fifth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        }
    else{
            [...document.getElementsByClassName("second-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("third-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("forth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
        [...document.getElementsByClassName("fifth-column")].forEach(e => e.style.display = "table-cell");
    }
    }
```

Hope it will helpful for someone